# nginx reverse-proxy sending client IP instead of server IP

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, reverse-proxy, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to use nginx as a proxy for an elasticsearch cluster (using Kibana for Logstash).  My elasticsearch ndoes are located behind an F5 load balancer and I want to use an iRule to drop all traffic except from my nginx IPs.  What happens is that the IP of the computer I connect to the nginx front-end with get's passed to Elasticsearch instead of the nginx IP.

I've tried using the proxy_bind option with the IP of the nginx server but had the same issue.  My config is below, can someone please help?

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {

            listen              80;
            server_name         logstash.domain.com;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
        }

        location ~ ^/_aliases$ {
        proxy_pass http://logstashdbaccess.domain.com:9200;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
        }

        location ~ ^/.*/_aliases$ {
        proxy_pass http://logstashdbaccess.domain.com:9200;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
        }

         location ~ ^/_nodes$ {
        proxy_pass http://logstashdbaccess.domain.com:9200;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
        }

        location ~ ^/.*/_search$ {
        proxy_pass http://logstashdbaccess.domain.com:9200;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
        }

        location ~ ^/.*/_mapping {
        proxy_pass http://logstashdbaccess.domain.com:9200;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
        }


        location ~ ^/kibana-int/dashboard/.*$ {
        proxy_pass http://logstashdbaccess.domain.com:9200;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        limit_except GET {
        proxy_pass http://logstashdbaccess.domain.com:9200;
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
        }
        }

        location ~ ^/kibana-int/temp.*$ {
        proxy_pass http://logstashdbaccess.domain.com:9200;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        limit_except GET {
        proxy_pass http://logstashdbaccess.domain.com:9200;
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set these headers in each proxy pass block

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
```

Otherwise rails will think that the request is originating from nginx itself to rails aka `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify what should these values be?  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for would be the IP of the proxy and $server_name the server name of the proxy?

Comment: you are telling nginx to forward these values to the rails app, so rails will know what the client ip is ( the ip for who's requesting the page ) and the server_name is the domain name that was requested ( so `example.com` instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Actually the client IP already seems to be sending.  I want to stop this and have the server IP sent the app instead.  That way I can lock down the app so only the nginx front ends can connect.

Comment: because they are accessible by port number you mean ? you could block that using iptables

Comment: I did that through iptables but since I am using a load balancer it.  I have this iRule to lock it down but it requires I add the IP of each client computer connecting.  `when HTTP_REQUEST {     
    if { [class match [IP::client_addr] equals logstashdb_allowed_IPs] } {        
        pool logstashdbaccess.domain.com_9200             
        log local0. "[IP::client_addr] is allowed"            
    } else {        
         HTTP::respond 403 content {403 Forbidden}         
         log local0. "[IP::client_addr] is blocked"
    }   
}`